# unable to start the Activity from the service class in Android

Tags: android, android-activity

Hai tried to get the latitude and longtitude value using service class.my service function is working very fine.but i canot start the activity for gpsclass.am getting force close.i added the class in manifest file also

**manifest file**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="com.javaorigin.android.sample.service"
  android:versionCode="1"
  android:versionName="1.0">
 <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />
 <application icon="@drawable/icon" label="@string/app_name">
   <service class=".MyService" android:name=".MyService">
     <intent-filter>
       <action android:value="com.javaorigin.android.sample.service.MY_SERVICE"
               android:name=".MyService" />

       </intent-filter>
   </service>
  <activity android:name=".SampleAction"

             android:label="@string/app_name">
             <activity android:name=".getLocation"/>
       <intent-filter>
           <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
           <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
       </intent-filter>
   </activity>

 </application>
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION" />
  </manifest>
```

**Logcat Message**

```
  01-12 14:12:08.911: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4071): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start service com.javaorigin.android.sample.service.MyService@44ee3168 with Intent { cmp=com.javaorigin.android.sample.service/.MyService }: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.javaorigin.android.sample.service/com.javaorigin.android.sample.service.getLocation}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
  01-12 14:12:08.911: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4071):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:3063)
  01-12 14:12:08.911: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4071):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$3600(ActivityThread.java:125)
  01-12 14:12:08.911: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4071):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2096)
  01-12 14:12:08.911: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4071):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
  01-12 14:12:08.911: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4071):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
  01-12 14:12:08.911: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4071):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
  01-12 14:12:08.911: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4071):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
  01-12 14:12:08.911: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4071):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
  01-12 14:12:08.911: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4071):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
  01-12 14:12:08.911: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4071):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
  01-12 14:12:08.911: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4071):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
  01-12 14:12:08.911: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4071): Caused by: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.javaorigin.android.sample.service/com.javaorigin.android.sample.service.getLocation}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
 01-12 14:12:08.911: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4071):     at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1404)
01-12 14:12:08.911: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4071):     at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1378)
01-12 14:12:08.911: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4071):     at android.app.ContextImpl.startActivity(ContextImpl.java:622)
01-12 14:12:08.911: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4071):     at android.content.ContextWrapper.startActivity(ContextWrapper.java:258)
 01-12 14:12:08.911: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4071):     at com.javaorigin.android.sample.service.MyService.onStart(MyService.java:25)
 01-12 14:12:08.911: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4071):     at android.app.Service.onStartCommand(Service.java:420)
01-12 14:12:08.911: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4071):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:3053)
01-12 14:12:08.911: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4071):     ... 10 more
```

my code

```
public class MyService extends Service {

 String tag="TestService";
private Intent Information;
 @Override
 public void onCreate() {
   super.onCreate();
   Toast.makeText(this, "Service created...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();      
   Log.i(tag, "Service created...");
 }

 @Override
  public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {      
   super.onStart(intent, startId);  
    Intent i=new Intent(getBaseContext(),getLocation.class);
   i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
   this.startActivity(i);       Log.i(tag, "Service started...");
 }
 @Override
  public void onDestroy() {
   super.onDestroy();
   Toast.makeText(this, "Service destroyed...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
 }

  @Override
  public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
   return null;
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apply this code,this will start your Receiver

```
      Intent myIntent = new Intent ( context, getLocation.class );
        myIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        context.startActivity(myIntent);
```

Answer (score 0):

Seriously...?

```
Caused by: android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: Calling startActivity() from outside of an Activity  context requires the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag. Is this really what you want?
```

Comment: Intent i=new Intent(getBaseContext(),getLocation.class);
       i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
       this.startActivity(i); i tried this also

Comment: i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK); Not **addFlags** but **setFlags**

Comment: i update my code,am trying with i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK); its getting force close.Shall i paste my manifest file

Answer (score 0):

```
01-12 14:12:08.911: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4071): Caused by: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.javaorigin.android.sample.service/com.javaorigin.android.sample.service.getLocation}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml
```

Declare your activity in your `manifest` file.

Comment: please check your package:   package="com.javaorigin.android.sample.service" ------- I don't think this is the right package declaration.

Comment: Try with full package declaration for activity in the manifest file e.g:<activity android:name="full package path.getLocation"/>

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6637/discussion-between-user1126160-and-vineet-shukla)

Answer (score 0):

```
   Intent myIntent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), myActivity.class);
   myIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
   getApplication().startActivity(myIntent);
```

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried passing a different context besides baseContext?  I feel like I remember that context might not be what you want, try passing applicationContext for example

```
Intent i=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),getLocation.class);
```

instead of

```
Intent i=new Intent(getBaseContext(),getLocation.class);
```

Comment: same force close.i think problem is manifest file.Shall i update now?

Comment: yeah if you don't have it in the manifest then that is definitely the problem

Comment: ya if i add new class its getting force close